# Weird mongo-pytest-asyncio interaction

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, pytest, python-asyncio

I've stacked with a weird problem using pytest-asyncio.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session', autouse=True) 
async def init_db(event_loop):
    DBClient(loop=event_loop, test=True)
    db = DBClient()
    db.drop_collection('db1')
    db.drop_collection('db2')

    item1 = {
        "name": "something"
    }

    item2 = {
        "name": "something"
    }
    params = {"name": ["hue", "hon"]}
    check1 = await db["db1"].insert_many([item1, item2])
    check2 = await db["db2"].insert_one(params)

    yield True

@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def event_loop():
    with loop_context() as loop:
        yield loop


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def client(event_loop):
    app = init_app(event_loop)
    with TestServer(app=app, host="0.0.0.0", loop=event_loop, port=8000) as server:
        with TestClient(app_or_server=server, loop=event_loop) as cl:
            event_loop.run_until_complete(cl.start_server())
            yield cl
```

I'm trying to create collections in a mongo database, but somehow time-to-time one of that collections doesn't create. But if I debug that "check1" or "check2" they always have values, even if there are no values added into database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Added "await" to these functions, works right way

```
 await db.drop_collection('db1')
 await db.drop_collection('db2')
```